# JQuery calendar not displaying booked dates from database as marked

Tags: jquery, calendar

I have this jquery calender where multiple dates can be selected and pushed to an array. These dates are saved in db later. This part works fine.

Later after refreshing the page calendar doesn't show all those dates as marked.

Dates in database are stored as a string in single cell. I have tried to return it as a string as well as array after exploding it. Doesn't work.

Her is my code:

```
var preSavedDates = [];

// Function1 Starts
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'../includes/ajax/availabily_dates_fetch.php',
    data: "&listingID=" + listingID,
    datatype: 'json',
    success:function(response){
        preSavedDates = response;
        //alert([response]);
    }
});
// Function1 Ends

$('#show-next-month').calendar({
    num_next_month: 11,
    num_prev_month: 0,
    unavailable: preSavedDates, // Here is the variable needed
    //unavailable: ['2019-2-5','2019-3-6','2019-1-25'], Works
    onSelectDate: function(date, month, year, thisEvent){
        var dateData = [year, month, date].join('-');
        dateClickEvent(dateData, thisEvent);
    }
});

// Function2 to cross check if variable exists
alert(preSavedDates);
// Function2 Ends
// Produces - 2019-2-5,2019-3-6,2019-1-25
```

I expect dates from database to be highlighted in the calendar.

Comment: which js plugin are you using for this calendar?

Comment: It's a phpJabbers calendar, https://www.phpjabbers.com/free-availability-calendar-script/

Answer (score 1):

It was silly me.

Calendar was getting initialized on document ready, and values for dates were fetched on an event at later time.

So calendar was considering default `var preSavedDates = [];` value.

Now that I have set calendar to initialize at the same time of fetching dates, it's working now.